# Where are failed installed Android system images in Windows

Tags: system, android-sdk

I was trying updating my Android System Image via Android SDK Manager. It was downloaded but failed to install because unfortunately, all C: disk memory was exhausted. I tried finding it in temp directories but wasn't there. I need to delete those failed system images and want to change the directory of temporary download location/installation of system images. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your clear the download cache from SDK manager:

[image]

If you believe you downloaded the system images, but failed to install them then probably they were extracted to respective directories i.e `User\Android\android-sdk\system-images` and in SDK manager they should show as broken with a typical icon like shown below:

[image]

It could be that you aren't able to start your AVD or emulator is complaining of low space on C: drive then you have to delete the .tmp files in this directory: `Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator`

[image]

Ironically, I  actually have a temp file of around 1.5GB (not sure why its there as I clear up my temporary files regulary).

Also make sure other unnecessary files are clear in your PC e.g emptying recycle bin etc.

I not really sure if there is a way to change the sdk temp directory in Windows.